# Show alert and interact using UIKit in SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI so please excuse me if i am writing something wrong. I have a SwiftUI file. Inside this SwiftUI file i have the following code. I need help doing two things. How do i show the alert i created in UIKit at the center of the screen above the TestView? Second how can i tap 'edit profile' and call a function?

```
       import SwiftUI
        import UIKit
    
    public struct TestView: View {
        
            @State var show: Bool
    
        public var body: some View {
        Button{
        UIAlertViewPopup(show: $show, title: "test", message: "test")
              } label {
                 Text("tap me")
                  }
        }
    
        struct UIAlertViewPopup: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
            typealias UIViewControllerType = UIAlertController
        
            @Binding var show: Bool
        
            var title: String
            var message: String
        
            func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIAlertViewPopup>) -> UIAlertController {
        
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { (action) in
                    self.show = false
                }
        
                let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit profile", style: .default) { (action) in
                    self.show = false
                }
        
                alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                alert.addAction(submitAction)
        
                return alert
            }
        
            func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIAlertController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIAlertViewPopup>) {
        
            }
        
            func makeCoordinator() -> UIAlertViewPopup.Coordinator {
                Coordinator(self)
            }
        
            class Coordinator: NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate {
        
                var control: UIAlertViewPopup
        
                init(_ control: UIAlertViewPopup) {
                    self.control = control
                }
        
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to return your own custom `UIViewController` from `makeUIViewController` and then present the `UIAlertController` using that. In `updateUIViewController` you can use the value of `@Binding var show: Bool` to decide if to present/hide the alert. You also need to update its message and title (Note: I'm not sure if `UIAlertController` allows that after it has been shown in which case you'll have to hide and present again).

Also, your `UIAlertViewPopup` should be above or below the `Button` or part of its label, not in its action.

Here is a sample I made:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public struct UIAlertTest: View {
    
    @State var show: Bool = false
    @State var title = ""
    @State var message = ""
    
    public var body: some View {
        Button("Show"){
            title = "Title"
            message = "Message"
            show = true
        }
        .task(id: show) {
            if show {
                // test updating the alert 2 secs after it has been presented.
                do {
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
                }catch {
                    return
                }
                title = "Updated Title"
                message = "Updated Message"
                
                // test programatically hiding the alert 2 + 3 = 5 seconds after it has been presented.
                do {
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
                }
                catch{
                    return
                }
                show = false
            }
        }
        .background {
            UIAlertViewPopup(show: $show, title: title, message: message)
        }
    }
    
    struct UIAlertViewPopup: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        @Binding var show: Bool
        
        var title: String
        var message: String
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator()
        }
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIAlertViewPopup>) -> UIViewController {
            context.coordinator.viewController
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIAlertViewPopup>) {
            
            if show {
                if let alert = context.coordinator.alert {
                    // just update its properties if it is already showing
                    alert.title = title
                    alert.message = message
                }
                else {
                    // create an alert and present it
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    context.coordinator.alert = alert
                    uiViewController.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
                // update the didHide closure to use the new version of the binding in case it changed.
                context.coordinator.didHide = {
                    show = false
                }
            }
            else {
                // dismiss the alert if the binding was just changed.
                // if an alert button was tapped it will already be dismissed and be nil by now because it is a weak var.
                if let alert = context.coordinator.alert {
                    alert.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
        
        class Coordinator: NSObject {
            
            lazy var viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
            var didHide: (() -> Void)?
            
            weak var alert: UIAlertController? {
                didSet {
                    if let alert {
                        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { [weak self] action in
                            self?.didHide?()
                        }
                        
                        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit profile", style: .default) { [weak self] action in
                            self?.didHide?()
                        }
                        
                        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                        alert.addAction(submitAction)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```